How can I encode/decode a Swift dictionary with Obj-C objects as keys to and from JSON?
I have a Dictionary<ObjcType, SwiftType> that I have to serialize to and deserialize from JSON. SwiftType conforms to Codable. ObjcType is a class written in Objective-C (used by one of the libraries I heavily depend on, so cannot change it to be in Swift). All properties of ObjcType are either NSString or BOOL.
I did some search and added these functions to ObjcType, to give it some semblance of serialization:
-(NSString*)GetJSON{
    NSError *writeError = nil;

    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:self options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&writeError];

    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    return jsonString;
}

- (instancetype)initWithObject:(NSString *)jsonString {
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil)
    {
        NSData* jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSDictionary  *object = [NSJSONSerialization
                                 JSONObjectWithData:jsonData
                                 options:0
                                 error:&error];
        for (NSString *dictionaryKey in object) {
            self.field1 = [[object valueForKey:dictionaryKey] objectForKey:@"field1"];
            self.field2 = [[object valueForKey:dictionaryKey] objectForKey:@"field2"];
            self.field3 = [[object valueForKey:dictionaryKey] objectForKey:@"field3"];
        }
    }
    return self;
}

So now my ObjcType can create its own text to put into that JSON.
But I cannot figure out how to make a wrapper that will encode\decode this dictionary. Any help?
P.S. even better is it could work with OrderedDictionary from OrderedCollections module instead of normal Dictionary.

JSON only supports strings for keys and doesn't support ordering, so using a OrderedDictionary wouldn't help anything. People could probably answer this question, but you can help them by giving them a short/simple snippet they can copy/paste and edit easily, showing the kind of dictionary you're looking to serialize

Order is not actually important for saving this, only for other operations. That is why I asked about a normal Dictionary.

You can write a wrapper like this:
@propertyWrapper
struct Wrapper: Codable {
    struct StringCodingKey: CodingKey {
        var intValue: Int? { nil }
        let stringValue: String
        
        init?(intValue: Int) { return nil }
        init(stringValue value: String) { stringValue = value }
    }
    
    var wrappedValue: [ObjcType: SwiftType]
    
    func encode(to encoder: any Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: StringCodingKey.self)
        for (key, value) in wrappedValue {
            // assuming there is property called 'jsonString'
            let keyString = key.jsonString
            try container.encode(value, forKey: StringCodingKey(stringValue: keyString))
        }
    }
    
    init(wrappedValue: [ObjcType : SwiftType]) {
        self.wrappedValue = wrappedValue
    }
    
    init(from decoder: any Decoder) throws {
        var wrapped = [ObjcType: SwiftType]()
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: StringCodingKey.self)
        for key in container.allKeys {
            // assuming such an initialiser exists
            let objcKey = ObjcType(json: key.stringValue)
            wrapped[objcKey] = try container.decode(SwiftType.self, forKey: key)
        }
        self.wrappedValue = wrapped
    }
}

Usage:
// decoding
JSONDecoder().decode(Wrapper.self, from: someJson).wrappedValue

// encoding
JSONEncoder().encode(Wrapper(wrapped: yourActualDictionary))

You can also use it as a property wrapper in other Codable types:
struct SomeOtherCodableType: Codable {
    @Wrapper var dict: [ObjcType: SwiftType]
}

